# Storing values as real data type in PostgreSQL. Confusion about the concept of precision

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am confused about the real data type in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE number_data_types (
    numeric_column numeric(20,5),
    real_column real,
    double_column double precision
);

INSERT INTO number_data_types
VALUES (.7, .7, .7),
    (2.13579, 2.13579, 2.13579),
    (2.1357987654, 2.1357987654, 2.1357987654)
);

SELECT * FROM number_data_types;
```

The output in the 3rd row, 2nd column is 2.1357987. Since the real data type in PostgreSQL has a precision of 6, the number of digits in a number that can be stored is 6. I expected to see the number 2.13579, because there are 6 digits in the number. What's wrong with my thought?

In my textbook, the author writes: "On the third row, you see PostgreSQL's default behavior in those two columns, which is to output floating-point numbers using their shortest precise decimal representation rather than show the entire value."

Answer (score 0):

The precision on a real is *at least* 6 digits. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT)...

> On all currently supported platforms, the real type has a range of around 1E-37 to 1E+37 with a precision of **at least** 6 decimal digits.

When displayed a real (aka float4) can display up to 9 digits.

> By default, floating point values are output in text form in their shortest precise decimal representation; the decimal value produced is closer to the true stored binary value than to any other value representable in the same binary precision. (However, the output value is currently never exactly midway between two representable values, in order to avoid a widespread bug where input routines do not properly respect the round-to-nearest-even rule.) This value will use at most 17 significant decimal digits for float8 values, ***and at most 9 digits for float4 values.***

[Floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) try to cram a lot of precision into a very small space. As a result they have a lot of quirks.

Comment: Ok, but what is the explanation that the number is stored as 2.1357987 and the three last digits are cut off? I don't understand the explanation in the textbook, is there an explanation in other words, or with an example?

Comment: Go here [Numeric datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) and then section *8.1.3. Floating-Point Types* and in that section start reading from *By default, floating point values are output in text form in their shortest precise decimal representation; ...* Also read [extra_float_digits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-EXTRA-FLOAT-DIGITS). Bottom line, if you don't want to deal with all that just stick with the `numeric` type.

Comment: @aurumpurum "*the number is stored as 2.1357987*" - it is not. It is stored as a binary value, something like `0b1000100010110000111011010 * (2 ** 0b0000001)`

Comment: Ok, but the output is 2.1357987.